# Check url status without opening it

Tags: django, redirect, middleware, dispatch

At Now when url is opened (without a slash - `example.com/blog`), a slash is automatically added at the end (there are `301` redirects). The question is, can I somehow do it so that the check first goes to see if the page exists (without a slash - `example.com/blog`). If so, open it. If not, then check whether the page exists with a slash (only without `301` - `example.com/blog/`). If so, then redirect `301`, and if not, then throw `404`.

Now just if there is no page (`example.com/blog`), then a slash is added to the end first (`example.com/blog/`), `301` redirects go and only then a `404` error is thrown. In this case, the `404` error must be thrown immediately, without a `301` redirect.

The `dispatch` was rewritten as follows.

```
def is_normal_slash_count(url):
    temp_url = url
    slash_count = 0
    while temp_url.endswith('/'):
        slash_count += 1
        temp_url = temp_url[:-1]
    return (slash_count == 1, slash_count)


def replace_bad_slash(url, slash_count):
    if slash_count == 2:
        return url.replace('//', '/')
    return url.replace('/'*(slash_count-1), '')


def normalize_url(url):
    if len(url) > 1:
        if not url.endswith('/'):
            return url + '/'
        # replace the url like /contacts//// to /contacts/
        good_slash, slash_count = is_normal_slash_count(url)
        if not good_slash:
            url = replace_bad_slash(url, slash_count)
    return url

def is_bad_url(url):
    if len(url) > 1:
        good_slash, slash_count = is_normal_slash_count(url)
        if not good_slash:
            return True
    return False

class RedirectMixinView:

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = self.request.path

        redirect_setting = RedirectSettings.objects.filter(url_from=url).first()
        if redirect_setting:
            return redirect(redirect_setting.url_to, permanent=True)

        if is_bad_url(url):
            return redirect(normalize_url(url), permanent=True)
        return super(RedirectMixinView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this realistic?

I think in the direction of writing `middleware`.

[image]

*Updated*

**projects.urls**

```
url(r'^page/', include('pages.urls')),
```

**pages.urls**

```
url(r'^$', PageView.as_view(), name='page'),
```

**test**

```
try:
    resolve('/page/')
except:
    raise Http404
return redirect('/page/')
```

I'm tried `/page/, /page, page/, page, http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/, http://127.0.0.1:8000/page`

Comment: Have you disabled [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) in your settings?

Comment: Then I think I already told you yesterday to use `resolve` to check if the URL exists. But again, you **cannot** check if the URL might return 404 if the 404 comes from the view itself.

Comment: Yes. I have a `APPEND_SLASH=False` in my settings.

Comment: literally or are you making a typo now?

Comment: Sry, this is a typo

Comment: Then use `resolve()` function to check if the URL exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to remove `RedirectMixinView` from `LandingView`.
2. Comment out the *middleware* `CommonMiddleware`.
3. Add `RedirectMiddleware` to the *list of middleware* (preferably in the top).
4. Create `RedirectMiddleware`

The code is written jointly with **@dirkgroten** (most of his contribution).

```
import re
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

class RedirectMiddleware(object):
    response_redirect_class = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)

        path = re.sub("/+", "/", request.path)

        if response.status_code == 404:
            if not path.endswith('/'):
                request.path = path  # to force using the cleaned path
            else:
                request.path = path[:-1]  # to force using the cleaned path
            try:
                full_path = request.get_full_path(force_append_slash=True) # add the slash, keeping query parameters
                r = resolve(full_path)
                new_response = r.func(request, args=r.args, kwargs=r.kwargs)
                if new_response.status_code == 200:
                    return redirect(full_path)
            except Resolver404:
                pass  # this will fall through to `return response`

        # Add the Content-Length header to non-streaming responses if not
        # already set.
        if not response.streaming and not response.has_header('Content-Length'):
            response['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))
        return response
```

5. Add to **ngnx config** of project

```
    if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)      $scheme://$host/$1    permanent;
    }
    # merge_slashes off;
```

It does what you need, and also *removes duplicate slashes if this page exists.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198401/discussion-on-answer-by-m0nte-cr1st0-check-url-status-without-opening-it).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you set `APPEND_SLASH` to `False` in your settings.py. This will disable the automatic 301 redirects to the URLs with slash.

Then use `resolve()` to check if the URL with slash exists before redirecting. Do this in a Middleware class where you handle the case that the `response` status code is 404.

```
from django.urls import resolve

try:
    resolve(url_with_slash)
except Resolver404:
    raise Http404
return redirect(url_with_slash)
```

Note that `resolve(url)` will not raise an exception when there is a path matching the `url`, even if the view might afterwards still raise a 404. This is the case for example if you have a `DetailView` for an object where the object's pk is in the URL. Say you have ***/objects/`<pk>`/*** as the path to show your objects, then the url ***/objects/4/*** will always match even if object with pk=4 does not exist. The view will still raise a 404 after the redirect.

So if you really want to also catch those 404's, you could actually call the view function yourself to check the response:

```
try:
    r = resolve(url_with_slash)
    response = r.func(request, args=r.args, kwargs=r.kwargs)
    if response.status_code == 200:
         return redirect(url_with_slash)
except Resolver404:
    pass
```

Comment: Updated. 
Somehow I get 404 anyway

Comment: I was assuming @pythoner was doing all of this in the middleware. @m0nte-cr1st0's response gives the correct approach for this (location of the code) but as I comment above, you should use `resolve()` not `requests`.

Comment: @dirkgroten The fact is that if there is a regular expression that several options can fit (as you wrote), then 404 will not. It is necessary to catch such a case, but resolve is incapable of this ...

Comment: Just a question: you really think this is good functionality? Why do you have this requirement in the first place? I would say that duplicating requests to your server (request in a request just to check the response before redirecting the client to repeat the same request) is far worse behaviour.

Comment: then first resolve, if it resolves, call the view function returned by resolve to check the response. Don't use `requests`.